# getting insights about a page

Tags: facebook-insights

I am trying to get the page insights.. the only metrics being shown are `page_fans_country` and `page_storytellers_by_country`. For rest of the metrics the following output is coming

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/22754734656/insights/page_fan_adds?since=1364712822&until=1364972022",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/22754734656/insights/page_fan_adds?since=1365231222&until=1365490422"
  }
}
```

Even if there is no addition in the no of fans '0' value should come as the output.. I am stuck.. Please help

Thanks

Comment: I do have read_insights permission

Comment: To get most of the insights data for a page, you need a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/). The documentation isn't very clear about this.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it won't answer the question correctly but...

Those insights are public so you just need an `App`, `Page` or `User` access token to request them.

However, Facebook is struggling to have its insights working properly. They use to be 3 days delay, now it's 5 days sometime. And now for few days it's not returning anything if you don't specify the date range. ie:

`/cocacola/insights`
 is not returning anything but sometime it is (latest insights)

To fix it few weeks ago I've read that specifying the metric would do it, and yes:
`/cocacola/insights/page_fans_country,page_storytellers_by_country`

But now it's not anymore. The only thing working is if you specified `since` and `until`

ie: `/cocacola/insights?since=1368503760&until=1368662399`

But it's really a pain in the ********* because you need to know which date is the latest available before to query your insights.

Facebook API sucks!